# Logging ALL Queries on a SQL Server 2008 Express Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, logging, ssms

Is there a way to tell SQL Server 2008 Express to log every query (including each and every SELECT Query!) into a file?

It's a Development machine, so the negative side effects of logging Select-Queries are not an issue.

Before someone suggests using the SQL Profiler: This is not available in Express (does anyone know if it's available in the Web Edition?) and i'm looking for a way to log queries even when I am away.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

SQL Server Profiler:

- File → New Trace
- The "General" Tab is displayed.
- Here you can choose "Save to file:" so its logged to a file.
- View the "Event Selection" Tab
- Select the items you want to log.
- TSQL → SQL:BatchStarting will get you sql selects
- Stored Procedures → RPC:Completed will get you Stored Procedures.

More information from Microsoft: SQL Server 2008 Books Online - [Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)

*Update - SQL Express Edition:*

A comment was made that MS SQL Server Profiler is not available for the express edition.
There does appear to be a free alternative:  [Profiler for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition](http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/)

Comment: I have not personally tried this, but here it is:    
Profiler for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition   http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/

Comment: When I get to work tomorrow I will try out that alternative program against mssql 2008.

Comment: The tool I Suggested does not currently support 2008, but I downloaded the source code, updated the project references to reference the 2008 sdk and then the application worked. I've emailed the maintainer to request he update the project.

Comment: Update: (1.) The tool does not appear to support saving the log to a file. (2.) If you want help getting the source code, and updating the tool to work for you, email me at kylelanser@yahoo.ca

Comment: I've tried the free tool and it doesn't seem to show me the actual SQL queries. Just how long they took. May be using it wrong though.

Comment: Select SPStmtStarting at "AnjiLab Sql Profiler" to dump SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations.

Comment: I used SqlProfilerExpress (Open Source) and it worked very well.  I'm not a DBA but I got a basic trace going and got what I needed.

Comment: They seem to be charging for SQL Profiler Express now, and the old versions close upon open claiming there is a new version available...

Comment: I just wanted to mention, that you can get the `SQL Performance Profiler` from  datawizard.com (that's where you'll end up when you visit https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) as a free trial for 14 days and for $20 to use on 3 servers. I'm not affiliated with them but I think this is worth noting since people might turn away from this solution just because of someone mentioning that it's not free anymore. Also, it allows to **export** the trace to XML.

Answer (score 32):

There is one more way to get information about queries that has been executed on MS SQL Server Express [described here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/03/sql-server-2005-last-ran-query-recently-ran-query/).

Briefly, it runs smart query to system tables and gets info(text, time executed) about queries(or cached query plans if needed). Thus you can get info about executed queries without profiler in MSSQL 2008 Express edition.

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 28):

…Late answer but I hope it would be useful to other readers here…

Using SQL Server Express with advanced auditing requirements such as this is not really optimal unless it’s only in development environment.

You can use traces (www.broes.nl/2011/10/profiling-on-sql-server-express/) to get the data you need but you’d have to parse these yourself.

There are third party tools that can do this but their cost will be quite high. [Log explorer](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) from ApexSQL can log everything but select and [Idera’s](http://www.idera.com) compliance manager will log select statements as well but it’s cost is a lot higher.

Comment: Has this improved with the profiler that comes with SQL Server 2014 Express?

Answer (score 3):

You can log changes.  SQL Server 2008 will make this especially easy with Change Data Capture.  But SQL Server isn't very good at logging SELECTs.

It is theoretically possible with the profiler, but it will kill your performance.  You might "get away with it" on your desktop, but I think you'll notice your machine acting slow enough to cause problems.  And it definitely won't work after any kind of deployment.

One important point a couple others have missed already: unless they changed something for 2008 I didn't hear about, you can't trigger a SELECT.

Comment: Thanks. Well, this is a development machine, so Performance is not an issue if I can turn on/off that feature. Capturing Selects in Production environments seems like a recipe for disaster anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I'm including the hints to use [DataWizard's SQL Performance Profiler](http://www.datawizard.com/Home/tabid/55/Default.aspx) as a separate answer since it's really the opposite to the [answer pointing at SQL Server Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123828/177710).

There is a free trial for 14 days, but even if you need to buy it, it's only $20 for 3 servers (at the moment of writing, 2012-06-28). This seems more than fair to me considering the thousands everybody using SQL Server Express edition has saved.

I've only used the trial so far and it offers exactly what the OP was looking for: a way to trace all queries coming in to a specific database. It also offers to export a trace to an XML file. The paid version offers some more features but I haven't tried them yet.

**Disclaimer:** I'm just another developer messing with DBs from time to time and I'm in no way affiliated with DataWizard. I just so happened to like their tool and wanted to let people know it existed as it's helped me out with profiling my SQL Server Express installation.

Comment: It rubs me the wrong way when a company decides to take a product that was previously open source and free, then completely buries the free version to sell it. I understand putting time into a project and wanting to monetize it. But leave the old versions out there, and don't pull a Red-Gate (.Net Reflector) where you deactivate someone's working installation. I only used Anjlab because it was free. If I'm going to spend $20 on a tool, I guess I'd rather spend $50 to get the SQL Server Developer Edition that includes SQL Profiler and pretty much everything else SQL Server has to offer.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for your comment. I wasn't aware there was a `Developer Edition` of SQL Server! $50 is a pretty awesome deal. And I agree with your point that old versions of the software should still be available. But for new users, I don't feel the pain, really. They either buy it or they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use triggers or use a third party software such as Red Gate to check out your SQL log files.

Comment: Red Gate Log Rescue only delivers inserts, updates and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can create traces using T-SQL

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283790/

That might help.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query below can show simple query logs:

```sql
SELECT last_execution_time, text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats stats
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(stats.sql_handle) 
ORDER BY last_execution_time
```

This is how it looks like below:

[image]