# Solutions for database access logging SQL Server 2008/ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, security, sql-server-2008, logging

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web app with SQL Server 2008 back end.

There's a new requirement to log all the database access as follows:

For Selects:

1. What stored procedure was executed
2. What parameters were passed

For Inserts:

1. What stored procedure was executed
2. What parameters were passed
3. Log inserted row(s)

For Updates:

1. What stored procedure was executed
2. What parameters were passed
3. Log old row(s)
4. Log new rows(s)

For Deletes:

1. What stored procedure was executed
2. What parameters were passed
3. Log deleted row(s)

There's also a reporting requirement, but that's not that important at the moment.

Before I start writing my own logger, I was wondering if there's any solution out there that does this?

[Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) looks promising, but only logs data changes (no Selects)

**p.s.: My web app has a "local install" option where user buys the source code and hosts the app, so SQL Profiler will not work as a logger as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123781/3661)**

Comment: We use a debug writer with Linq, and something similar when using Entity Framework.  It was designed to output the queries run to the debug window, and I believe they're easy to google.  If you're using an ORM, perhaps you could adapt these TextWriters (that's what they are basically) to output to a log somewhere?

Comment: @Smudge202: I'm not using ORM

Comment: the app is build on top of DotNetNuke framework, I use DNN's DAL to access the DB.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DNN, but if it comes to writing your own logging, I'd look to see if you can use log4net or one of the other similar logging frameworks.

Comment: Do you really need to roll your own logger, or can you get by using SQL Profiler? If this is for ongoing logging then I'm guessing the former, but if it's just ad hoc or temporary the profiler might serve.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trace using tsql to capture all of the above. Since you mentioned that you cannot use the Profiler, simply use the system stored proc sp_trace_create to create the trace. user activity can be logged in a trace file. You can specify the max. size of the trace file and also intervals when you want to rotate the log files. Some of the other system SPs that you will need are:

- SP_TRACE_CREATE
- SP_TRACE_SETEVENT
- SP_TRACE_SETFILTER
- SP_TRACE_SETSTATUS

for reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188662.aspx

for tutorial: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Running_Traces_with_TSQL