# Echo literal string?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-prompt, xp-cmdshell

I have an SQL procedure that calls the command shell to write an SQL dump to a file. Take this redacted file for example:

```
VALUES(
  @SomeVar
  ,1
)
```

The procedure calls:

```
echo VALUES(>> C:\somefile.sql
echo @SomeVar>> C:\somefile.sql
echo ,1>> C:\somefile.sql
echo )>> C:\somefile.sql
```

This works fine, except for the `,1` line. If you run `echo ,1>> C:\somefile.sql` in CMD, you will see that C:\somefile.sql only contains `,`

My theory is that `echo` *thinks* it can accept more than 1 parameter.

If you modify the command to `echo ,1blah>> C:\somefile.sql`, it works perfectly.

I could modify my procedure to check if the line contains a `,` followed by a number, not followed by anything, and prepend `^` to the number to escape it. This is a bit of a pain though.

Also, `echo 1>> C:\somefile.sql` writes `Echo is ON`

Is there a way to `echo` a literal string in CMD? Enclosing the string in `" "` outputs the `"` marks. Or is there any other solution you can think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `1` is the file descriptor for the [standard output stream](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php) in batch files / `CMD.EXE`. You can work around this by using this line instead:

```
echo ,1 1>> C:\somefile.sql
```

Or, but more fragile, just put a space between the `1` and the `>>` redirection

```
echo ,1 >> C:\Somefile.sql
```

*Update*: If you are really concerned about the trailing whitespace for the above examples, you could also use

```
>> C:\Somefile.sql echo ,1
```

I.e. you can also put the redirection in front of the command. Personally, I think it looks a little awkward, but YMMV.

Comment: But that isn't a problem concerning valid SQL/UPDATE statement syntax, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few routes to go here:

1. Put the redirection at the start of the line:

   ```
   > file echo foo
   ```
2. Put the `echo` in parentheses:

   ```
   (echo foo) > file
   ```

In the latter case you *have* to escape closing parentheses as `^)`, in the former you *might* have to, depending on how the surrounding code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the trailing number.

```
echo ,^1> C:\Somefile.sql
```

Comment: Rephrasing my answer: that is the *only* solution for your problem.

Comment: +1, I had no idea you could escape the 1 to avoid it being treated as the file descriptor. Pretty cool. But it is not the only solution. You can also get the correct output without a trailing space by putting the redirection in front: `>c:\somefile.sql echo ,1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can output a literal string. Any and all arguments to echo are redirected. The problem is you do not have a space between your string and the redirect. `1>` and `1>>` are special versions of `>` (pipe output to file, replacing if it exists) and `>>` (pipe output and append to file, creating it if it does not exist). They redirect the standard output (stdout in C++, Console.Out in C#). `2>` and `2>>` redirect the standard error output (stderr in C++, Console.Error in C#).

For example:

```
echo 111 > a.txt
echo 111 1> a.txt
```

are equivalent.

Comment: The problem with this is that it writes `111[space]` to the file

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using echo? You can just do `copy con somefilel.sql` then enter your SQL and end it with a control-Z character/F6 (end of file). The latter part might be harder, though.

Comment: This is perfect! No escaping whatsoever required!! I'm pretty sure I can just do `CHAR(26)` to get an EOF. Thanks a lot @akton - I will mark this as the accepted answer as soon as I check out the EOF.

Comment: Unfortunately, after converting all of the `echo`s in my procedure to `INSERT INTO #Temp`s and trying `copy con`, I couldn't for the life of me find a way to mirror either the CR/LF or EOF. I tried ASCII codes 10, 13, and 10 & 13 for CR/LF and 4, 26 and probably a couple more for EOF/EOT... nothing worked! :(

Comment: @DannyBeckett Can you modify your question to include the contents of our xp_cmdshell script, please?

Comment: Done - it just executes and executes and executes (i.e. still waiting for input) @akton

Comment: @DannyBeckett Let's take a step back for a second. Why are we logging the SQL to a file? If you just want to trace the output, why not log the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123781/logging-all-queries-on-a-sql-server-2008-express-database?

Comment: The procedure is to backup all procedures, functions and triggers in a specified schema that match a specified pattern.

Comment: Why not export all the schema (see http://forums.asp.net/t/1667081.aspx/1 for an example) then filter that? It sounds like you are doing things the hard way. There is also a powershell script for it at http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/powershell-script-export-sql-schema-definition. xp_cmdshell is also a significant security risk and most DBAs disable.

Comment: The schema is enormous - several gigs of data. This is to export procedures from a development environment to a customer's environment. It automatically adds `WITH ENCRYPTION` in the correct places etc. All of the data generated by the procedure is done in < 1 second. The procedure is run as a DBA, therefore there is no risk of xp_cmdshell being disabled.

Comment: How about using sp_helptext (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) to output the text of each procedure?

Comment: sp_helptext is limited to 255 characters per line. Also, it uses deprecated sys tables. My solution takes the definition directly: `SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('someschema.someproc')`. However, with either solution, `copy con` still does not work.

Comment: Is there a reason why this has to run as a stored procedure? Can you write a short application that connects to SQL, runs the query you provided above and writes the procs out to files?

Comment: I agree that's the best solution. Unfortunately this is a case of "the customer's always right". If I could just get line feeds/end of file working, this would be perfect with `copy con`

Comment: @DannyBeckett Well, I've had a good muck around myself and I cannot get it to work. I assumed that the control-Z character is not an EOF character itself but is being interpreted by cmd.exe to end the file and this appears to be correct. The closest I could get was http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=132685 but that said it did not work. I would look at Joey's solution.