# sql server high index usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012 and have a table in my database with 10 rows that no have query in sql server profiler usually. But when I use `dm_db_index_usage_stats` for survey usage of indexes, the primary key index of this table have high `user_update` and `user_seek`.

I don't know why this index have high update and seek.

The average update for this unused table is about 1000 updates per minute.

**Edit**

this table don't have any foreign key with another table and don't have any dependency.

I think that this problem was a bug in sql server.

**EDIT 2**

When I drop and recreate this table and insert data on it again, the index usage of this table did not change.

I think perhaps exists some tables like this table (with no usage and have index update and index seek).

**EDIT 3**

I write an after update trigger on this table, and save updated record to another table **(`JohnLBevan suggest`)** but don't insert any record on new table, that mean this trigger don't run. but index user_seek and index user_update change still. I firmly believe that this problem is a bug in SQL Server. but I don't know these update and seek are effective on performance.

**Edit 4**

I use below code to get index usage :

```
SELECT *
From
(SELECT  DB_NAME(ddius.database_id)AS DatabaseName, OBJECT_NAME(ddius.object_id) AS object_name , 
       CASE 
        WHEN ( SUM(user_updates + user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups) = 0 ) 
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE ( CAST(SUM(user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups) AS DECIMAL) 
                    / CAST(SUM(user_updates + user_seeks + user_scans 
                               + user_lookups) AS DECIMAL) ) 
        END AS RatioOfReads , 
       CASE  
        WHEN ( SUM(user_updates + user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups) = 0 ) 
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE ( CAST(SUM(user_updates) AS DECIMAL) 
                    / CAST(SUM(user_updates + user_seeks + user_scans 
                               + user_lookups) AS DECIMAL) ) 
        END AS RatioOfWrites , 
        SUM(user_updates + user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups) 
                                                  AS TotalReadOperations , 
        SUM(user_updates) AS TotalWriteOperations 
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS ddius 
        JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON ddius.object_id = i.object_id 
                                 AND ddius.index_id = i.index_id 
WHERE   i.type_desc IN ( 'CLUSTERED', 'HEAP' ) --only works in Current db 
GROUP BY ddius.database_id,ddius.object_id) Z 
ORDER BY TotalWriteOperations desc --OBJECT_NAME(ddius.object_id)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient relevant information
 

Comment: unused tables do not get updated.

Comment: unused tables must be not get update. but this table have high update with no use.

Comment: "this table have high update with no use." - I'm sorry but one of those facts must be untrue.

Comment: @MitchWheat; Please sell My edit.

Comment: Can you add an update trigger to the table which writes to another table on update - i.e. use that to confirm whether an update's actually happening / maybe record what's being updated to get a better idea of what's going on?  To your knowledge the table shouldn't be updated, but the evidence suggests otherwise - so perhaps some investigation's required?

Comment: @JohnLBevan. Thanks. I will do investigation and report.

Comment: @JohnLBevan. please see my Edit3.(report of your suggest).

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anthonybloesch/archive/2012/12/07/sql-server-performance-investigation.aspx

Comment: There's still a chance that somebody does updates and rollbacks, so that the DML, called in the trigger are rolled back either. Try to trace the accesses to the table-object to see if anybody (and who) is actually updateing the table. [Here's how tracing can be set up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123781/logging-all-queries-on-a-sql-server-2008-express-database)

Comment: @jboi. don't exists any query about this table on sql server profiler.

Comment: Post the exact code you use to query the view, including how you join to retrieve the actual object names from the IDs in the view. Most likely the problem is there and you're just looking at the wrong table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
From
(SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(ddius.object_id) AS object_name , 
      ...
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS ddius 
        JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON ddius.object_id = i.object_id 
                                 AND ddius.index_id = i.index_id 
WHERE   i.type_desc IN ( 'CLUSTERED', 'HEAP' ) --only works in Current db 
GROUP BY ddius.object_id) Z 
ORDER BY TotalWriteOperations desc --OBJECT_NAME(ddius.object_id)
```

The query is incorrect. `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` will return entries from the entire server (all DBs) but you're joining with whatever is the current DBs `object_id`/`index_id`. The results are incorrectly aggregating entries from all DBs and presenting them as usage in current DB. Add `ddius.database_id = DB_ID()` to the `WHERE`:

```
WHERE   i.index_id <= 1 -- clustered or heap
 AND ddius.database_id = DB_ID()
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. I will assign bounty when able the system permit (after 24 hour).