# Get SQL statement from a parameterized sql query

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have the below code:

```
string cmdText="select * from [TestTable] where [TestColumn]=@testparam";            
var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testparam", "hello");
```

Is there an way to get the sql statements being sent to the database engine? I am using SAP B1 DI API which have a Recordset object that takes the sql string as parameter. I could have used  escaped values for parameters to prevent sql injection. Also, please let me know if it is possible with some other external library or I need to escape the parameter values manually.

Comment: The query that is sent is the query you have in the string. The only difference is that the parameters are attached to the end with their type.

Comment: may be you can use the database feature like trace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123781/logging-all-queries-on-a-sql-server-2008-express-database

Comment: I am also finding the solution but all in vain. Finally I had to debug manually. But it becomes problematic when you have large number of columns and you are using parametrized query. SQL Server Prifiler can be handy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, I think [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173757%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is your solution.

Using this tool, you're able to listen to every query and action, that could be invoked by your C# code. In this way, you'll be able to understand which statements are sent to the RDBMS engine.