# Issue running developer cross-reference in AX 2009

Tags: security, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, cross-reference

I'm trying to run the AOT cross-reference in AX2009, path from GUI is
 and with
the Update Data Model & Update Type hierarchy fields checked.

I receive the following error when attempting the above:

> User is not
>   authorized to delete a record in table 'XREFTABLERELATION'.Request denied.
>   Cannot edit a record in Table relations (xrefTableRelation). Access denied:
>   You do not have sufficent authorization to modify data in database.

This is a test DB so I should have all rights, went to Security/Development
/Tables and saw I had full control of nodes Cross-Reference (ID: 516, config Key
SysDevelopmentMorphX, security Key SysDevelopmentTables) and Cross-referenced
AOT paths (ID: 515, config Key SysDevelopmentMorphX, security Key
SysDevelopmentTables), but not node Cross reference Type Hierarchy
(ID: 554, config Key SysDevelopmentMorphX, security Key SysDevelopmentTables).
This node says no access. I'm assuming that's the problem but not sure.

I'm stuck here. Does anyone have a idea how to make this work?
K

Comment: Could you add the error message?

Comment: (line 1) Update cross-reference (w/recompile) (line 2) Update Data Model (line 3, red X icon) User 'kmurr' is not authorized to delete a record in table 'XREFTABLERELATION'. Request Denied. (line 4, red X icon) Cannot edit a record in Table relations(xRefTableRelation). Access Denied: You do not have sufficient authorization to modify data in database.

Comment: My boss says I have the exact same admin rights he has and doesn't know how to proceed. He's an ex-SAP guy and I've never had to get involved with this before.

Answer (score 0):

You will need full access, Admin rights, as well as patience and available database space in the 10 GB range.

Comment: Thanks for answering, saw your WC team, best so far. Could you possibly detail exactly how to tell if I have full access and admin rights? My new VP claims I have all of this but he was an SAP guy so I'm unsure of his expertise, how could I check?

Comment: error message is...(line 1) Update cross-reference (w/recompile) (line 2) Update Data Model (line 3, red X icon) User 'kmurr' is not authorized to delete a record in table 'XREFTABLERELATION'. Request Denied. (line 4, red X icon) Cannot edit a record in Table relations(xRefTableRelation). Access Denied: You do not have sufficient authorization to modify data in database.

Comment: You should probably address this issue by tracing the SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123781/logging-all-queries-on-a-sql-server-2008-express-database

Comment: I get the following message from SSP <in order to run a trace against SQL Server you must be a member of sysadmin fixed server roile or have the ALTER TRACE permission>, sheesh.

Comment: Your database admin should give you the permissions needed.